# Sending an OPTIONS request in Android is not working

Tags: android, .net, httpwebrequest

I am trying to send an OPTIONS request from my android application to my Windows 2008 Server webservice (which is a .net webservice).  I am using SSL, and am having difficulty getting this to work.  I really need to know exactly what my headers should look like.  I know I don't send the body, I just need to know what to send.  I really need an example not a link to someone just talking about some things.

Comment: Basically an example of the xml to send like the request headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.  It was working.  I just wasnt looking in the right place for my response.  I was looking at the final response that I get from my Soapbuilder class, and I am stripping out the headers before returning.  I is actually giving the right options headers back.